# If $y=x^{n-1}\ln (x)$, then prove that $xy_{n}=(n-1)!$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=x^{n-1}\ln (x)$, then prove that $xy_{n}=(n-1)!$

My Attempt:
$$y=x^{n-1}\ln (x)$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$,
$$y_{1}= x^{n-1} \dfrac {1}{x} + \ln (x)\cdot (n-1)x^{n-2}$$

P.S $y_{n}$ denotes the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y$.

Comment: Your last three questions basically fall in the category of the same kind of question. What does really bother you about differentiation?  That's a question worth of MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=x^{n-1}\ln (x)$$
$$\implies y_1=(n-1)x^{n-2} \ln (x)+x^{n-2}$$
$$\implies xy_1-(n-1)y=x^{n-1}$$
Now differentiating $(n-1)$ times with the help of Leibnitz's Formula we have,
$$xy_n+^{n-1}C_1y_{n-1}\cdot 1-(n-1)y_{n-1}=(n-1)!$$
$$xy_n+(n-1)y_{n-1}-(n-1)y_{n-1}=(n-1)!$$
$$\implies xy_n=(n-1)!$$

---

> **Leibnitz's Formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of a product:**
>
> If $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$, each possessing derivatives upto $n^{th}$h order, then the $n^{th}$ derivative of their product is given by
>
> $$(uv)_n=u_nv+^nC_1 u_{n-1}v_1+^nC_2u_{n-2}v_2+\quad. . . \quad+^nC_ru_{n-r}v_r+\quad. . . \quad+ uv_n$$

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed by induction.

Note that if $y = x^n \ln x$ then $$y_1 = x^{n - 1} +n x^{n - 1} \ln x.$$ Taking derivative $n$ times and using the hypothesis give us $$y_{n + 1} = 0 + n\frac{(n - 1)!}{x}.$$
The conclusion follows.